# WPF button automationproperties.name bind to 2 values

Tags: asp.net, wpf

How to bind button AutomationProperties.name in wpf to 2 values
like that
AutomationProperties.Name="text1 + {Binding automationPropertiesNameInspectMode}"

and

AutomationProperties.Name="text2 + {Binding automationPropertiesNameTestMode}"

```
<Grid x:Name="ictMainMenu" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                         DockPanel.Dock="Top" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                         WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" 
                         Margin="0,90,0,0"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Once">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Button x:Name="btnInspect" 
                            Height="40" Width="40"                                                                
                            ToolTip="Inspect" Style="{StaticResource btnLeftNav}"

                            AutomationProperties.Name="text1 + {Binding automationPropertiesNameInspectMode}" 
                            Click="btnInspect_Click">
                        <Grid Width="40" Height="40">
                            <Canvas x:Name="cvsInspect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="7" Height="Auto" Background="#FFFFFF" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <fabric:FabricIconControl GlyphName="SearchAndApps" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#eaeaea"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="btnTest" 
                            Height="40" Width="40" 
                            Grid.Row="1"                         
                            ToolTip="Test"
                            AutomationProperties.Name="text2 + {Binding automationPropertiesNameTestMode}" 
                            Click="btnTest_Click"
                            Style="{StaticResource btnLeftNav}">
                        <Grid Width="40" Height="40">
                            <Canvas x:Name="cvsTest" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="7" Height="Auto" Background="#ffffff"/>
                            <fabric:FabricIconControl GlyphName="TestBeakerSolid" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#eaeaea" Margin="12,0,12,12" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use Binding String format for this .

```
<Button Content="Open" Height="50" Click="Button_Click"
   AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding ButtonAccessibleName ,StringFormat=test{0}}"/>
```

[bindingbase.stringformat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or if you want more control you can use Converters like this :

```
AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding CurrentPlant,    
        Converter={StaticResource     
            CurrentPlantToAutomationPropertiesNameConverter}}">
```

Link : [part-2-set-the-automationproperties-name](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winuiautomation/2015/03/19/giving-your-xaml-element-an-accessible-name-part-2-set-the-automationproperties-name/)

Answer (score 1):

I just updated it manually in the method that updates the window UI so it will be called every time the window is updated